Counterexample for an improper integral
$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ exists, but $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty |f(x)|dx=+\infty$.
I searched $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ may work, but I don't know how to show it is infinity.
Or there is any other example.

The standard example is $\frac{\sin x} x$

If there is no requirement on $f$, then the condition implies originally some part of $f$ are positive, and some are negative, and also both are very large. So a natural idea would be the periodic extension of $f(x)=\begin{cases}1\quad& x\in[0,1]\-1&x\in(1,2)\end{cases}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

@AngaeMT your idea does not work because $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x f(t),dt =1$ and $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x f(t),dt =0$.

Oh yes, so shall be considering some convergent impropert integral
